# How to make popup window not fill whole screen?

Tags: android, android-fragments, popup, popupwindow

Go stucked with this one, hope you can help me to figure this out. So the problem is: I need to make a popup window in android app that would not fill all the space on screen and would be place below action bar. It should leave some space in the bottom as well(as seen on the screen)

[image http://imageshack.com/a/img904/3365/ViHyHG.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img904/3365/ViHyHG.jpg)).

Spent some time on it and still cant see and solution. Hope you will help me.

Comment: did you used custom layout for popup window ??

Comment: LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.service_price_popup, null);
            pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, true);
            pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);

Comment: Tried to play with LayoutParams and margins/padding in xml as well.

Comment: use layout margin in your xml.Did you tried this ??

Comment: post your xml code here

Comment: Its too big, here is [link](http://rghost.net/59237469)